# Using library products without gradle files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I would like to create an app based around [this](https://github.com/zh-wang/YWeatherGetter4a) library in Android Studio. However, it doesn't have gradle files and it doesn't seem to work without them. How would I use this library in Android Studio?

Comment: The home page of that project says that it's a Library Project, and links here: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrate the library from Eclipse to Android Studio, using [Migrating from Eclipse](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html).

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I forgot about that, I haven't used eclipse in at least a year.